# AWS EC2 server refusing Ionic/Capacitor/Android connections to PHP files

Tags: php, angular, amazon-ec2, ionic4, capacitor

I have recently begun building an Angular Ionic app which connects to  PHP scripts on an AWS EC2 server. Everything works fine except for when I try to connect through Android once the app is built on my phone.

The response is a simple 404 response with no additional information. When I look at the log on Android Studio I see the following response:

> E/Capacitor: Unable to open asset URL: [*api address*]

I have reduced both the HttpClient call on the frontend and the php file on the backend to their most simple forms and yet still nothing:

```
<?php
     echo "Hello";
?>
```

I know that Capacitor was updated to 3 only a couple of months ago and am concerned that it is related to that. I am using PHP 7.

**UPDATE**
The issue was indeed **cleartext** but the issue was made more complicated by the fact that HttpClient was not catching the error and so I was simply getting back an unknown failed response.

In order to first see that it was cleartext I first had to change HttpClient for the Native HTTP plugin and check the logs whilst testing on my phone (HTTP will not work through the browser).

Only then did I notice that I hadn't changed the config file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your PHP web server is not running on the Android device directly trying to connect to `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` won't work and you need to use another domain / IP your web server is available on and which the Android device can access. You can also check this by simply opening the URL in the browser of the Android device.

If that is not feasible for you you could also use [port forwarding via adb](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/) to forward a port of your web server to a local port on the Android device.

If you use another domain / IP make sure your web server is not listening to local connections only and is not blocked by a firewall or similar.

Also if you are using an unencrypted connection (i.e. `http` instead of `https`) you might need to enable the `cleartext` config option in you [Capacitor config](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#schema).

Comment: Firstly, regarding localhost / 127.0.0.1, I was not aware of that. Thank you. I have added "cleartext": true to the json object located at capacitor.config.json as well as changed the location of the api to our online server. I don't even get an error code now - nothing...

Comment: If your apk is a debug build you can use chrome devTools for [remote debugging the WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) of your Capcitor app. This should give you more insights on what is going on.

Comment: I am using it, thanks. I have now created a new ionic app and done simple get request to a test.php file. The file contains only headers for CORS plus an echo statement. Everything works again - except when I run it on Android! My code could not be any more basic. Could this be related to SSL certification??